# Compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008) runs much slower than 90 (SQL Server 2005)?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know why the following scripts run much faster with compatibility level 90 (SQL Server 2005) (about 40ms) than 100 (SQL Server 2008) (more than 5 seconds)?

```
declare @i int = 0, @x xml, @v varchar(max) = '<A><X>x</X><Y>y</Y><Z>z</Z></A>', @t datetime = getdate()

while @i<1000
begin
    set @v = @v+'<A><X>x</X><Y>y</Y><Z>z</Z></A>'
    set @i = @i+1
end

set @x = convert(xml,'<root>'+@v+'</root>')

declare @tb table (X varchar(20), Y varchar(20), Z varchar(20))

insert into @tb (X, Y, Z)
select t.c.value('X[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    t.c.value('Y[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    t.c.value('Z[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from @x.nodes('/root/A') AS t(c)

select count(*), datediff(ms,@t,getdate()) from @tb
```

Note, when `insert into @tb (X, Y, Z)` is commented out, it runs quick.

Comment: Yeah. Different execution plans. Want to know more? Well, what about you - get the execution plans and publish them and then ask for an analysis?

Comment: And what is the actual database version?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My version is "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)". The plans are a little bit different in XML Reader that caused 100 11 times slower in EstimateCPU. You may try with your SQL2008 see what else you find. I added "DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (@DBID)" before the script. The exec time was 100=5173ms; 90=36ms. 100 is 143 times slower. Is there any way to force 100 to use 90 execution plan?

Comment: Detail of execution plan difference: Compatibility level 100 uses:
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:(XML Reader with XPath filter.[id]<=XML Reader.[id] AND [Expr1054]>XML Reader.[id]))
EstimateCPU = 0.0418

Compatibility level 90 uses:
|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:(XML Reader with XPath filter.[id], [Expr1054]))
EstimateCPU = 0.003762